# How to use sweet alert on button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

message like that

```
Swal.fire(

  'Good job!',

  'You clicked the button!',

  'success'

)
```

When I click my button then I want to show that message

Answer (score 0):

```js
function alertMsg(){
 Swal.fire(
  'Good job!',
  'You clicked the button!',
  'success'
)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.3.3/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<button onClick="alertMsg()">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to achieve this, I don't know if your button has an id or class you can attach an event for that, you should use the on click event.
Learn more about [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) here.

This is a simple example:

```
<button onclick="showSwalAlert()">My Button</button>
<script>
 function showSwalAlert(){
    Swal.fire(
    'Good job!',
    'You clicked the button!',
    'success'
   )
  }
</script>
```